# Gridview copy cell value of a column to all other cells of the column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a lot of rows in my gridview which are filled manually. However some columns have always the same value. So instead of manually entering the same data over and over again, I want to add a data to the top of the column, and when a button is clicked, I want all the column cells to be filled with the same value. I am looking for ways to do it at the moment but couldn't find an easy way at the moment.

Edit: Until now I added an image button to the header row [0], and when clicked the image button clicked event fires. I can get the cell in row [0] but not in row[1], because I don't know how to find the column identity. If I will be able to reach cell value of this specific column, then I will copy it to the rest of the column

Comment: You said `some columns have always the same value.` , that means some other columns have different value . How did you fill manually ? Can you show me some code ?

Comment: @zey Think of it as one of the most used functions of excel, I have manually filled the cells in excel, but sometimes, I enter a value to one cell, and when I click to the buttom right of this excel cell, it copies the value to all the other cells in this column. Actually my code is nothing but a regular gridview with edit enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to dynamically set same data to all  rows of a dataset and assing that dataset to grid.

```
for (int i = 0; i < customers.rows.count; i++)
        {               
            customers.Rows[i]["<your column name>"] = "<your default text>";                
        }
```